# Clear input when Submit is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am having an input field and a button. When I click the button, the input field should clear itself. My HTML is:

```
<input type="text" id="search_number" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

And the js is:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
     $('#search_number').value = '';
});
```

It doesnt works.. Thanks..

Comment: I see you made a cheeky edit! My answer still stands.

Comment: If the form is submitted (if there is a form), why exactly would you need to clear the value, or are you trying to not submit the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly specify that the selector for `search_number` is an identifier (by prefixing with a `#` (hash)), and use `val()` instead (which will *get* the value if no value is specified, and *set* the value of one is):

```
$("#search_number").val("");
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this:

```
$('#search_number').val("");
```

1. Your selector did not have the # for an id
2. You can't use `.value` with jQuery but `.val()`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to set the value. Passing in an empty string will clear the value:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
     $('#search_number').val('');
});
```

Also, the hash (#) was missing from the selector for search_number

Working example - http://jsbin.com/ilutar/1/

Answer (score 1):

its

```
$('#search_number').val('');
```